# View Quick Action Lightning Component as pdf

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, printpdf

I have this below lightning component from where I am calling a lightning web component. This lightning component is called from quick action. I need to print this content as pdf.

When I click the button, the quick action page overflows with the object detail page.

I have a restriction that I cannot use VF page.

Lightning Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId">
    <lightning:button label="Print To PDF" title="Print To PDF" onclick="{! c.myAction }"/>
    <c:TestLWC recordId="{!v.recordId}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller -

```
({
    myAction : function(component, event, helper) {
             window.print();
    }
})
```

Thanks for help

Comment: What does you mean when you say quick action page overflows with the object detail page?

Comment: Means when the print page opens, i can see the object details page and the quick action modal has got transparent...